# Creating Graphs and using them for path-finding algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, path-finding

I am creating a program that randomly creates a maze, where every square can be reached from another. The next step I want to include in this program is a way to connect the paths from one square to another, preferably using [Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

However, this means I need to turn the MAze into a graph, like so:
[image]

How do I code this, I have never worked with algorithms like this before, and have no experience with this, so I will really need almost every step that is necessary to go from figure a to figure be explained to me.

Here is the code for maze creation:

```
public void GenerateMaze()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        for (int z = 0; z < mazeHeight; z++)
        {
            MazeCells[x, z].Walls[0] = true;
            MazeCells[x, z].Walls[1] = true;
            MazeCells[x, z].Walls[2] = true;
            MazeCells[x, z].Walls[3] = true;
            MazeCells[x, z].Visited = false;
        }
    MazeCells[0, 0].Visited = true;
    EvaluateCell(new Vector2(0, 0));
}

public void resetMaze()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        for (int z = 0; z < mazeHeight; z++)
        {
            MazeCells[x, z].Visited = false;
        }

    RandomWalls(new Vector2(0, 0));
}

private void EvaluateCell(Vector2 cell)
{
    List<int> neighborCells = new List<int>();
    neighborCells.Add(0);
    neighborCells.Add(1);
    neighborCells.Add(2);
    neighborCells.Add(3);

    while (neighborCells.Count > 0)
    {
        int pick = rand.Next(0, neighborCells.Count);
        int selectedNeighbor = neighborCells[pick];
        neighborCells.RemoveAt(pick);

        Vector2 neighbor = cell;

        switch (selectedNeighbor)
        {
            case 0: neighbor += new Vector2(0, -1);
                break;
            case 1: neighbor += new Vector2(1, 0);
                break;
            case 2: neighbor += new Vector2(0, 1);
                break;
            case 3: neighbor += new Vector2(-1, 0);
                break;
        }

        if (
            (neighbor.X >= 0) &&
            (neighbor.X < mazeWidth) &&
            (neighbor.Y >= 0) &&
            (neighbor.Y < mazeHeight)
            )
        {
            if (!MazeCells[(int)neighbor.X, (int)neighbor.Y].Visited)
            {
                MazeCells[(int)neighbor.X, (int)neighbor.Y].Visited = true;
                MazeCells[(int)cell.X, (int)cell.Y].Walls[selectedNeighbor] = false;
                MazeCells[(int)neighbor.X, (int)neighbor.Y].Walls[(selectedNeighbor + 2) % 4] = false;
                EvaluateCell(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Removes random walls
private void RandomWalls(Vector2 cell)
{
    List<int> neighborCells = new List<int>();
    neighborCells.Add(0);
    neighborCells.Add(1);
    neighborCells.Add(2);
    neighborCells.Add(3);

    while (neighborCells.Count > 0)
    {
        int pick = rand.Next(0, neighborCells.Count);
        int selectedNeighbor = neighborCells[pick];
        neighborCells.RemoveAt(pick);

        Vector2 neighbor = cell;

        switch (selectedNeighbor)
        {
            case 0: neighbor += new Vector2(0, -1);
                break;
            case 1: neighbor += new Vector2(1, 0);
                break;
            case 2: neighbor += new Vector2(0, 1);
                break;
            case 3: neighbor += new Vector2(-1, 0);
                break;
        }

        //Ensures that end piece is not deleted
        if (
            (neighbor.X >= 0) &&
            (neighbor.X < mazeWidth) &&
            (neighbor.Y >= 0) &&
            (neighbor.Y < mazeHeight)
            )
        {

            //if cell was not visited
            if (!MazeCells[(int)neighbor.X, (int)neighbor.Y].Visited)
            {
                Random random = new Random();

                MazeCells[(int)neighbor.X, (int)neighbor.Y].Visited = true;

                //if random number is >= a certain number, removes the walls on both ends
                if (random.Next(20) >= 15 && removed <= 100)
                {
                    //MazeCells[(int)neighbor.X, (int)neighbor.Y].Visited = true;
                    MazeCells[(int)cell.X, (int)cell.Y].Walls[selectedNeighbor] = false;
                    MazeCells[(int)neighbor.X, (int)neighbor.Y].Walls[(selectedNeighbor + 2) % 4] = false;
                    removed++;
                }

                RandomWalls(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for the lack of notes on the code, but this is what the maze end up looking like after it renders:

[image]

Comment: if you dont specify your current data structure it's hard to answer

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I don't follow, current data structure?

Comment: How do you represent the maze?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I added the code for creating it, I have individual cells set up, and then add walls. I also added a picture so it is easier to see the way it is set up. Each colored square is a single cell that want to be represented in the graph, if that makes the question clearer.

Comment: You don't need an explicit graph, you can just traverse the matrix as if it were a graph (treat the coordinates as nodes and non-walls between cells as edges).

Comment: @Dukeling Could you post an answer that shows me how to do this? I'm sorry, but I'm really am a bit inexperienced, and I have to be able to explain to my class how this is done (I was assigned a project where I need to explain to the class how to create a pathfinding algorithm)